# I am using Freezed bloc in my project. the project uses an API which has adding , deleting Etc. my state is not emitted in ui when I call create API

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

[The UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roKds.png),
[This is my alert box for Update and Create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz0hO.png) ,
I am calling my event in a alert box . and my API is calling is Success. but my state is not emitting. there is no problem when delete API is Called.
[This is the UI change  When deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WsYM.png)

have updated the code adding The Bloc , Event , State

```
class ProductsBloc extends Bloc<ProductsEvent, ProductsState> {
  final ProductsService _productsService;

  final MainService _mainService;

  List<ProductData> productOfflineList = [];

  List<ProductData> searchList = [];

  ProductsBloc(this._productsService, this._mainService)
      : super(const ProductInitialState()) {
    //* loadProduct event
    on<LoadProductDetails>(
      (event, emit) async {
        // Show Loading in UI
        emit(
          ProductLoadingState(),
        );

        //call service or call api
        final result = await _productsService.getProductDetails();

        // create state

        result.fold(
          (MainFailure failures) {
            emit(
              const ProductFetchErrorState(),
            );
          },
          (ProductsResp resp) async {
            productOfflineList = resp.data;
            emit(
              ProductListLoadedState(
                productList: resp.data,
                productSearchList: searchList,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );

    //* searching Products
    on<SearchProductDetails>(
      (event, emit) {
        log(event.name);

        for (var element in productOfflineList) {
          log(element.productName.toString());
          if (element.productName!
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(event.name.toLowerCase())) {
            log('added');
            searchList.add(element);
          }
        }
        if (searchList.isEmpty) {
          emit(
            const ProductSearchEmptyState(),
          );
        } else {
          emit(
            ProductSearchState(
              productList: productOfflineList,
              productSearchList: searchList,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );

    //*clear Search
    on<ClearSearchProductDetails>(
      (event, emit) {
        // final list = state.productList;
        searchList = [];

        // log(searchList.toString());
      },
    );

    // *create new product
    on<CreateProduct>(
      (event, emit) async {
        // emit(
        //   ProductLoadingState(),
        // );
        // log('create product');
        final result = await _mainService.createData(
          productName: event.productName,
          productCode: event.productCode,
          productUOM: event.productUOM,
          productPrice: event.productPrice,
        );
        result.fold(
          (MainFailure failure) {
            log('product adding false');
            emit(
              ProductCreatedFailedState(
                message: const MainFailure.clientFailure().toString(),
              ),
            );
          },
          (success) async {
            log('product added');

            emit(
              ProductCreatedSuccessState(
                message: success.data,
              ),
            );


          },
        );
      },
    );

    //* Update Product
    on<UpdateProduct>(
      (event, emit) async {
        log('Update');
        final result = await _mainService.updateData(
          productID: event.productID,
          productName: event.productName,
          productCode: event.productCode,
          productUOM: event.productUOM,
          productPrice: event.productPrice,
        );

        result.fold(
          (MainFailure failure) {
            log('Product update failes');
            emit(
              ProductUpdatedFailedState(
                message: result.toString(),
              ),
            );
          },
          (success) async {
            log('Product update true');
            emit(
              ProductUpdatedSuccessState(
                message: success.data,
              ),
            );

          },
        );
      },
    );

    //* Delete Product
    on<DeleteProduct>(
      (event, emit) async {
        final result = await _mainService.deleteData(
          productid: event.id,
        );
        result.fold(
          (MainFailure failure) {
            log('product not deleted');
            emit(
              ProductDeletedFailedState(
                message: result.toString(),
              ),
            );
          },
          (success) async {
            emit(
              ProductDeletedSuccessState(
                message: success.data,
              ),
            );
            log('product Deleted');
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}






class ProductsState with _$ProductsState {
  const factory ProductsState.initial() = ProductInitialState;

  factory ProductsState.loading() = ProductLoadingState;

  const factory ProductsState.fetchError() = ProductFetchErrorState;

  const factory ProductsState.productListLoaded({
    required List<ProductData> productList,
    required List<ProductData> productSearchList,
  }) = ProductListLoadedState;

  const factory ProductsState.productSearchList({
    required List<ProductData> productList,
    required List<ProductData> productSearchList,
  }) = ProductSearchState;

  const factory ProductsState.productSearchEmpty() = ProductSearchEmptyState;

  const factory ProductsState.productCreatedSuccess({
    required String message,
  }) = ProductCreatedSuccessState;
  const factory ProductsState.productCreatedFailed({
    required String message,
  }) = ProductCreatedFailedState;

  const factory ProductsState.productUpdatedSuccess({
    required String message,
  }) = ProductUpdatedSuccessState;
  const factory ProductsState.productUpdatedFailed({
    required String message,
  }) = ProductUpdatedFailedState;

  const factory ProductsState.productDeletedSuccess({
    required String message,
  }) = ProductDeletedSuccessState;
  const factory ProductsState.productDeletedFailed({
    required String message,
  }) = ProductDeletedFailedState;
}





@freezed
class ProductsEvent with _$ProductsEvent {
  const factory ProductsEvent.loadProductDetails() = LoadProductDetails;

  const factory ProductsEvent.deleteProduct({
    required String id,
  }) = DeleteProduct;

  const factory ProductsEvent.searchProductDetails({
    required String name,
  }) = SearchProductDetails;

  const factory ProductsEvent.clearSearchProductDetails() =
      ClearSearchProductDetails;

  const factory ProductsEvent.createProduct({
    required String productName,
    required String productCode,
    required String productUOM,
    required double productPrice,
  }) = CreateProduct;

  const factory ProductsEvent.updateProduct({
    required int productID,
    required String productName,
    required String productCode,
    required String productUOM,
    required double productPrice,
  }) = UpdateProduct;
}

















    productDialog({
    required context,
    required width,
    required bool isUpdate,
    int productID = 0,
    String productName = '',
    String productCode = '',
    String productUOM = '',
    double productPrice = 0,
  }) {
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    TextEditingController productNameCtrl =
        TextEditingController(text: productName);
    TextEditingController productUOMCtrl =
        TextEditingController(text: productUOM);
    TextEditingController productPriceCtrl = isUpdate
        ? TextEditingController(text: productPrice.toString())
        : TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController productCodeCtrl =
        TextEditingController(text: productCode);

    return AlertDialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.08),
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      title: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: width * 0.02),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(
              isUpdate == false
                  ? "  Enter item details"
                  : "  Update item details",
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.info,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      content: SizedBox(
        width: width * 0.9,
        // height: 120,
        // color: Colors.blue.shade100,
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              //* product name
              TextFormField(
                controller: productNameCtrl,
                // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: UtilControllers().mainColor)),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500)),
                  hintText: "Product name",
                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter Product Name';
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),

              //*Product code
              TextFormField(
                controller: productCodeCtrl,
                // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: UtilControllers().mainColor)),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500)),
                  hintText: "code",
                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter Product Code';
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),

              //* Peoduct UOM
              TextFormField(
                controller: productUOMCtrl,
                // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: UtilControllers().mainColor)),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500)),
                  hintText: "UOM",
                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter Product UOM';
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),

              //* product Price
              TextFormField(
                controller: productPriceCtrl,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: UtilControllers().mainColor)),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade500)),
                  hintText: "Unit Price",
                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter Product Price';
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),

              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: UtilControllers().mainColor),
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    isUpdate == false
                        ? BlocProvider.of<ProductsBloc>(context).add(
                            CreateProduct(
                              productName: productNameCtrl.text,
                              productCode: productCodeCtrl.text,
                              productUOM: productUOMCtrl.text,
                              productPrice: double.parse(productPriceCtrl.text),
                            ),
                          )
                        : BlocProvider.of<ProductsBloc>(context).add(
                            UpdateProduct(
                              productID: productID,
                              productName: productNameCtrl.text,
                              productCode: productCodeCtrl.text,
                              productUOM: productUOMCtrl.text,
                              productPrice: double.parse(productPriceCtrl.text),
                            ),
                          );
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  isUpdate == false ? 'Add Item' : 'Update Item',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

my bloc managment code is

```
BlocConsumer<ProductsBloc, ProductsState>(
       
        listener: (context, state) {
          log(state.toString());
          if (state is ProductCreatedSuccessState) {
            BlocProvider.of<ProductsBloc>(context).add(
              const LoadProductDetails(),
            );
            // Navigator.of(context).pop();
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                backgroundColor: UtilControllers.mainColors,
                content: Text("Product added"),
              ),
            );
          } else if (state is ProductDeletedSuccessState) {
            BlocProvider.of<ProductsBloc>(context).add(
              const LoadProductDetails(),
            );
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                content: Text("Product Deleted"),
              ),
            );
          } else if (state is ProductUpdatedSuccessState) {
            BlocProvider.of<ProductsBloc>(context).add(
              const LoadProductDetails(),
            );
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                backgroundColor: UtilControllers.mainColors,
                content: Text("Product added"),
              ),
            );
          } else if (state is ProductDeletedFailedState) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                content: Text("Product Deleted"),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is ProductLoadingState) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 2,
              ),
            );
          } else if (state is ProductFetchErrorState) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Error While Fecthing Data'),
            );
          } else if (state is ProductListLoadedState) {
            return ProductListView(
              width: width,
              height: height,
              state: state,
            );
          } else if (state is ProductSearchState) {
            return ProductListView(
              width: width,
              height: height,
              state: state,
            );
          } else if (state is ProductSearchEmptyState) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text("Not Found"),
            );
          }
```

Comment: Can you also share your bloc, event and state file code?

Comment: updated the bloc , event and state @AbhishekDoshi